# How to adapt a Spinner item to TexView

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

I my application insert data in database and save this data in listView. when a user click on item in listview, a this information is available to textView form. But how to adapt spinner item in textView?

```
package cm.mavis.crud2;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;


public class TampilPegawai extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private TextView editTextId;
private Spinner spinneragence;
private TextView editTextName;
private TextView editTextDesg;
private TextView editTextSalary;

private Button buttonUpdate;
private Button buttonDelete;

private String id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tampil_pegawai);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    id = intent.getStringExtra(Configuration.EMP_ID);

    spinneragence = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    editTextName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextDesg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextDesg);
    editTextSalary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextSalary);

    buttonUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
    buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

    buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

    getEmployee();
}

private void getEmployee(){
    class GetEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(TampilPegawai.this,"Fetching...","Patientez...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            showEmployee(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequestParam(Configuration.URL_GET_EMP,id);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetEmployee ge = new GetEmployee();
    ge.execute();
}

private void showEmployee(String json){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Configuration.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
        String agence = c.getString(Configuration.TAG_AGENCE);
        String name = c.getString(Configuration.TAG_NOM);
        String desg = c.getString(Configuration.TAG_POSITION);
        String sal = c.getString(Configuration.TAG_SALAIRE);

        spinneragence.
        editTextName.setText(name);
        editTextDesg.setText(desg);
        editTextSalary.setText(sal);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void updateEmployee(){
    final String agence = spinneragence.getSelectedItem().toString();
    final String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String desg = editTextDesg.getText().toString().trim();
    final String salary = editTextSalary.getText().toString().trim();

    class UpdateEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(TampilPegawai.this,"Mise a jour...","Patientez...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(TampilPegawai.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put(Configuration.KEY_EMP_ID,id);
            hashMap.put(Configuration.KEY_EMP_NOM,name);
            hashMap.put(Configuration.KEY_EMP_AGENCE,agence);
            hashMap.put(Configuration.KEY_EMP_POSITION,desg);
            hashMap.put(Configuration.KEY_EMP_SALAIRE,salary);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

            String s = rh.sendPostRequest(Configuration.URL_UPDATE_EMP,hashMap);

            return s;
        }
    }

    UpdateEmployee ue = new UpdateEmployee();
    ue.execute();
}

private void deleteEmployee(){
    class DeleteEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(TampilPegawai.this, "Mise a jour...", "Patientez...", false, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(TampilPegawai.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequestParam(Configuration.URL_DELETE_EMP, id);
            return s;
        }
    }

    DeleteEmployee de = new DeleteEmployee();
    de.execute();
}

private void confirmDeleteEmployee(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Voulez vous supprimer ce salarié?");

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Oui",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    deleteEmployee();
                    startActivity(new Intent(TampilPegawai.this,TampilSemuaPgw.class));
                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Non",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonUpdate){
        updateEmployee();
    }

    if(v == buttonDelete){
        confirmDeleteEmployee();
    }
}
}
```

Please help me to rectify this code.the spinner choice is insert correctly in database but how to show this in textView form?

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can style UI elements as things they are not. For example,

```
<style name="SpinnerText" parent="android:Widget.TextView"/>
```

then,

```
<Spinner style="@style/SpinnerText" .../>
```

You'll probably have to tweak that to get exactly what you are looking for, but you get the idea.

Comment: No my problem is java code look my code in a showemployee () function please